# Deal with NULL values in json response

Tags: json, go, null

I am confused about the treatment of json null values in Go.
Lets say I have the following example :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

type Fruit struct {
    Name    string
    Price   int
    Owner   string  
}




func main() {
jsonData := []byte(`
{
    "Name": "Standard",
    "Price" : null,
    "Owner": null
}`)

    var f Fruit
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &f)
    if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Name is : %s\nPrice is : %d\nOwner is : %s\n", f.Name, f.Price, f.Owner)
    if f.Owner == ""  {
        fmt.Printf("Name should be nil?\n")
    }
    if f.Price == 0  {
        fmt.Printf("Price should be nil?\n")
    }
}
```

Now, my main question is :

**What is the right way to differentiate a nil value from a default value?**

For instance, in the example below, I have no way to know if the price of the fruit has NOT been set or the actual price is zero.

How do you folks deal with this?

In other languages both string and ints can be null, but thats not the case in Go.

Comment: Use pointer types, e.g. `*int`/`*string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pointers:

```
type Fruit struct {
    Name    *string `json:"Name,omitempty"`
    Price   *int     `json:"Price,omitempty"`
    Owner   *string  `json:"Owner,omitempty"`
}
```

Then you can check if a field is nil, or if it has value or not.

However, this will not help you if you want to distinguish between the case where a field exists in the document and set to null and the field does not exist at all.